# Apply Pay - Missing transaction history if pay with Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, wallet, apple-pay

If I use Apple Watch to pay, I cannot receive notification and also no transaction history found in the Wallet app. Is it a bug?

Comment: surly it will be in your Emails? I doubt Apple would have made a bug as simple as this...

Comment: no email, no push, nothing